# Security Alert on Certificate on every load with Outlook 2010

Tags: email, outlook, certificate, exchange-server, autodiscovery

Each and every time I start Microsoft Office 2010 I get a Security Alert saying that there is a problem with the security certificate for `autodiscover.xxx.xxx`. I have followed the Certificate installation wizard to install the certificate on my machine, but even after a restart of the application I am still being prompted.

Do I have to restart the machine itself? I am using Windows 7.

[image: Security Warning]

Comment: Review the properties of the certificate.  What is the valid date range?  What are the subject and subject alternative names?   Regardless if you add the cert on the client computer, Outlook will still issue the warning.

Comment: To fix it, the cert on the Exchange CAS servers must be properly set up (subject alternative names, valid range, issued by trusted certificate authority)

Comment: I've just looked at the certificate and can see that it has expired, it was issued by `GeoTrust SSL CA` and is valid from `25/08/2011 to 25/09/2012`. So I assume that even with installing it i'll still get an alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the server certificate needs to be renewed.  However, it also looks like that certificate does not have a *Subject Alternative Name* entry for autodiscover.yourdomain.com, which is the second problem shown in the screenshot.

The CAS server(s) should have at a minimum the OWA FQDN (e.g. webmail.yourdomain.com) and autodiscover (e.g. autodiscover.yourdomain.com).  There are other considerations when setting up the cert request (such as load balancers, multiple datacenters, etc.)

You can use these as a references, or send to your Exchange administrator if you do not manage the infrastructure:

- http://exchangeserverpro.com/configure-an-ssl-certificate-for-exchange-server-2010
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351044(v=exchg.141).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Kill Outlook security certificate warnings

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover]
add:
   "ExcludeScpLookup" = DWord (32) : 00000001
   "ExcludeHttpsAutoDiscoverDomain" = DWord (32) : 00000001
   "ExcludeSrvRecord" = DWord (32) : 00000001
```

I have verified this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and tried to resolve it by importing the valid unexpired self signed certificate into "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" from the Certificate Warning dialogue, but the certificate did not import even though it said "Import Successful". I successfully imported the certificate through "Internet Options/Content/Certificate/Trusted Root Certification Authorities", after which I no longer got the Certificate warning (Problem Solved). Perhaps this may solve your problem.